# Rails Geocoder gem "not valid JSON"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using the Rails Geocoder gem and keep getting "response is not valid JSON" when I do a simple geocoding request. The format of the request is as follows,

```
Geocoder.search("Paris")
```

When I ask for the RAW data request, I get the correct data but it is formatted with a ton of JSON escape characters. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using ruby 2.0.0p195 (after a fresh `gem install geocoder`) I could successfully execute `Geocoder.search("Paris")`. We probably need more details about your system to reproduce your question.

Comment: Check your geocoder config file